# error in <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How can I resolve this?

When I am try to build a project directly from repository. It is giving this error at pointing to this line:

Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />

The error was command Error 1   The command "rmdir /s /q C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\img
move /y C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccr\xsl\img C:\Santosh SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\
move /y C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccr\xsl*.xsl* C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\
move /y C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccr\xsl*.xsd C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\
rmdir /s /q C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccr
move /y C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccd\xslt*.xslt C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\
rmdir /s /q C:\SVN\Glarus-EMR\branches\MC3\src\ERIICore\bin\Debug\ccd" exited with code 1.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4548    5   ERIICore

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the many commands in your postbuild event failed.  Look in the Output window for a diagnostic message.  If that doesn't help then divide-and-conquer, try one command at a time.

Comment: need the answer to this too

Answer (score 0):

You may copy the command and try to execute it in the command prompt.  In this case you will likely see a similar error.  `$(PostBuildEvent)` seems like multiple commands concatenated to a single string.  You may try to use `ItemGroup` to run each command separately, read [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) for more details.